# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year. [This is a link to the previous thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/community-promotion-ads-2012).

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6774).

Comment: This past year, Math was one of the most active of the sites for the community ads thread. This is also the first time Math is experiencing the yearly reset. We're looking at automating the process more for upcoming years, and I'd appreciate any feedback that can be given about the reset - if you like it the way it is, if you think it could've been done in a better way, etc.

Comment: I just copied over those entries from last year where I was the principal and/or most recent author. I suppose I could've done the rest too, but I figured I'd give their respective authors a chance to do it themselves.

Comment: I have to know, what happens if all the ads are below the threshold?

Comment: @Asaf Nothing gets shown. That's all. You just get the regular rotation of ads there, such as upcoming proposals or random questions from other sites.

Comment: What is the deadline for an ad?

Comment: @Graphth There is no time limit on how long it can take to accrue 6 score (if it ever does), and this thread will stay open for new posts all the way until December 2013, when I start the next thread. Any ad that reaches 6 will be on display for as long as it maintains that score. If I missed what you meant by "deadline", let me know what you're looking for exactly and I'll get you the right answer.

Comment: You answered my question exactly.  I thought perhaps you picked all the ads on a certain date and those are what were used for the following year.  But, I get it now.  Thanks!

Comment: [The following ad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ByYq0.png) showed up on TeX.SE, which is just totally wrong. Don't know where it originated from though.

Comment: @Werner You mean [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264544/how-to-find-number-of-prime-numbers-up-to-to-n)? We advert questions from the sites based on metrics like vote and view velocity, that is independent from the Community Ads system.

Comment: Aaahhh, I see. I thought it was one of the Community Ads generated a while back. The incorrect grammar made me wonder how such an ad would be approved. I'll delete my comments to keep this area clean.

Comment: @Werner No need for that - having the comments around helps explain to anyone else who might make the same mistake, it leaves a record that people can use.

Comment: Would http://us.metamath.org/ be an appropriate site?

Answer (score 63):

[image: arXiv.org -- open access to over 800 000 e-prints]

Comment: [From last year's thread.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3329/622)

Comment: It's now [800000](http://arxiv.org/show_monthly_submissions)...

Comment: @Pavel, well... $700,000\leq800,000\leq n$, where $n$ is the number of e-prints on arXiv. :-)

Comment: @Pavel, Asaf: Well, I fixed it anyway. For future reference, the font appears to be 18px [Aller](http://www.identifont.com/find?font=Aller).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, that's exactly right. You could've just asked, I think I still have the source file somewhere. (I'm the one who created this originally, if you didn't know)

Comment: @YiJiang: I didn't know that, actually. Anyway, I figured it was easy enough to "just fix it", but if you still have the originals and can make a better fix, please do. (This also reminds me that I really should put the originals for the ads I've made online somewhere, so that it's easier for others to tweak them...)

Comment: @YiJiang / ImariKaronen Could you please make an updated version (with 900 000 instead of 800 000) for next year?

Answer (score 58):

[image: The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences]

Comment: Copy of [this 2012 ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3387).

Answer (score 47):

[image: GeoGebra - Free mathematics software for learning and teaching]

Comment: Copy of [this 2012 ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3391).

Answer (score 46):

[image: ProofWiki, the online compendium of mathematical proofs]

Comment: Copy of [this 2012 ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3386).

Answer (score 38):

[image: Try Sage open-source mathematical software system]

Comment: The sudden change in font size between the two lines at the bottom is rather jarring.

Comment: I like Sage, but "easy to use" is not one of the first two things that come to mind when I think of it. "Comprehensive and free // mathematics software"?

Comment: Looking at the icon, I couldn't figure out what the name of the product was.  Scxge?  Soxge?  If it weren't for the above comment, I wouldn't have known it was Sage.

Comment: It's "easy to use" as follows: "Sage helps make it easier to interactively experiment with mathematical objects." As I interpret, it's easier than using a general-purpose programming language / spending thousands of dollars / using various free packages separately. Further goals: "It should be easy to understand what functionality is provided for a given object and to view documentation and source code. Also attain a high level of user support." In my experience it's doing pretty well on these fronts. http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments.
@RahulNarain (and voters) I've tried to make it less jarring, hope it helps.
Joe, That's the logo from the sage website, so I'm going to stick with it, I can see what you mean though.

Answer (score 37):

[image: writeLaTeX.com - great for writing math, and works on your iPad too!]

Comment: This is an ad from TeX SX, which may also be useful here - firstly, you can easily use it to collaborate & iterate to reach answers in math (not just in TeX), and secondly, it is a great option for working through mathematical problems on an iPad or other tablet (for which there are limited alternatives). Happy to let the community vote decide - I'm one of the developers of writeLaTeX, so any feedback appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Great tool! It'd be awesome if you added an image map to the preview linking back to the respective paragraph in the source, similar to links embedded in a `.dvi` that I have set `yap` to open in TeXnicCenter, or even made it highlight the paragraph in hovering (maybe including optional scroll-following...)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TobiasKienzler -- sorry for the late reply, I only just checked back on this page. You'll be pleased to hear we're planning to add preview linking to the source later in the summer :-)

Comment: Great to hear, can't wait to see this :-)

Answer (score 24):

[image: PlanetMath - Math for the people, by the people.]

Comment: Copy of [this 2012 ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3403).

Comment: Looks good.  We could add a new logo if you want!

Comment: @JoeCorneli: An updated version with the new logo would be nice indeed.

Answer (score 21):

[image: Khan Academy's Linear Algebra]

Comment: Why all the downvotes ? Those videos are excellent !

Comment: @Kasper I think the downvotes come from the design.

Comment: @ziyuang: Please do improve it.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen They have a logo actually https://khan-academy.appspot.com/images/khan-logo-vertical-transparent.png

Comment: @ziyuang: It is done

Answer (score 21):

[image: MIT OpenCourseWare - Free Online Course Materials]

Comment: Copy of [this 2012 ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3401/18873)

Answer (score 16):

[image: exwiki.org -- Wiki aimed at collecting math exercises]

Comment: I think this site is a good idea but its quite new and hence poor in content. I hope an ad here could invite more people to contribute to it.

Comment: I don't know anything about graphics, but the image seems a little "pixel-y" to me.

Comment: Indeed - hopefully the creators of the graphic can vector-ify the graphic or something. It's very grainy

Comment: @mixedmath: I have created my own version [i.stack.imgur.com/suFK1.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/suFK1.png). I don't know if I'm allowed, but I edited the post with it. Had to remove a couple lines and dots as they made the text kinda unreadable. I think it's nicer overall. Hope you like it!

Answer (score 16):

[image: Inversely Symbolic Calculator]

Comment: The inverse symbolic calculator tries to infer what probably is the "closed form" of the input.

Comment: I think the color scheme could use some redesign.

Answer (score 16):

[image: LaTeX handwritten symbol recognition]

Answer (score 15):

[image: Signal processing, statistical analysis, numerical optimization, and much more]

Comment: The text in the original version was badly kerned and poorly anti-aliased, so I retyped it. I'm not sure what the original font was, but my edited version uses Linux Libertine O.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks a bunch. After posting this one I realized that I wasn't meant to be a graphic designer. Don't even remember what font it was, but glad that it's gone.

Comment: To be fair, though, I'm pretty sure the poor kerning and anti-aliasing was more the fault of whatever software you were using.

Comment: The surface used in the ad looks rather flat or crowded/confused  and does not do a good job of showcasing a desired graphing capability. Perhaps this is due to limited number of pixels available. A simpler picture could do better.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Scientific Literature Digital Library & Search Engine]

Comment: Copy of [this 2012 ad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3385).

Answer (score 12):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: +1 I want Academia.SE to graduate; yet "Rocking your world since " seems unnecessary, poorly legible, and possibly Euro-centric.

Comment: @5PM I included it to give it a “motivational poster” style, but I'm happy for other designs (or variations) to be proposed (over at Academia.meta). Regarding Euro-centric, the main characters on the painting *are* Plato and Aristotle, so it's not only the text that may be guilty…

Comment: The relevance of Plato and Aristotle is unquestionable; I was wondering about the implication that there was no academic environment before 387 BC. Maybe this should be a question on Academia.SE :)

Comment: -1 for "rocking your world"

Answer (score 12):

[image: AMS Graduate Student Blog - Read and write about topics that matter to you.]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Crypto Stackexchange]

Answer (score 7):

[image: GAP - Group, Algorithms and Programming]

Comment: Extremely glad. I can sleep in peace having this software. Thanks for sharing it us. :-)

Comment: This is now reposted at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11926/70316 for the next year

Answer (score 5):

[image: Mathematica]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is an example ad to demonstrate, with the site's twitter account. Last year, it never stayed above the necessary 6 votes. This is perfectly fine, and I look forward to the volume of ads for more relevant services to the community.

Answer (score 4):

[image: The 2014 Joint Mathematics Meetings]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Check out the online [calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)...

Comment: This is not free, unlike Sage.

Comment: @LinuxDistance the online calculator is...

Answer (score 2):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: The academia Ad above, without "rocking your world".

Comment: Jarring triple repetition of "Academia".

Comment: The reason for the old black border was to give it a motivational poster style. Without any subtitle, this effect is already lost, so you might as well go all the way and get rid of the black border (and the first "ACADEMIA") entirely.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Derek Owens]

Comment: Why are you down-voting? Derek Owens' mathematics courses are at my eyes better than Khan Academy's ones.

Answer (score 1):

[image: free online $\LaTeX$ editing]

Comment: +1: But the graphics can be ameliorated.

Comment: Completely agree, but time prevented anything better than a 5 minute MS Paint graphic.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: ...they are referring to [Mathoverflow](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&limit=500&offset=0&redirs=1&profile=default&search=mathoverflow) quite a bit...