# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year. [This is a link to the previous thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/community-promotion-ads-2013).

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11920).

Answer (score 80):

[image: The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3387

Comment: Is there a reason why this isn't linked to the OEIS main page?

Comment: @Arthur I'm not sure, but IMHO search result page better demonstrates its usefulness.

Comment: What about linking the ad to a random page so each time one clicks on it, a new sequence will be displayed?

Comment: From an old discussion of (the first version of) this ad: «Wouldn't the ad be more effective if it linked to the relevant search query or straight to the relevant sequence? The sequence is what got me curious and made me click through, after all.»

Comment: Ah, one of the comments of the sequence that is currently linked to the ad actually says that its first 14 terms appear in the OEIS logo - then it seems to be a perfect candidate to be linked!

Comment: This one’s so useful that I even donate a little to them each year.

Answer (score 78):

[image: Detexify²]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11616/93957

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I suppose that people don't like that the page explicitly asks for donations.

Comment: Or because noone can draw beautiful curly braces like this with a mouse.

Answer (score 72):

[image: arXiv.org -- open access to over 800 000 e-prints]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6966/

Comment: Perhaps it is time to update the number to 900k?

Comment: @Asaf Well, arXiv doesn't yet have 900k preprints...

Comment: True. But by 2014 it ought to have that amount. This thread is for ads for 2014 (whether or not they appear now is a whole other thing)... Anyway, I think it is worth being prepared. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: finally, it's time to update: I've just seen it reporting 900,267 e-prints.

Comment: Huzzah! Next year: 1M.

Comment: Still says "800 000" ...

Comment: If someone could please update the number... (I've left a comment for Yi Jiang in the last year's thread but he haven't answered.)

Comment: I still had the GIMP .xcf file from [last year's fix](http://vyznev.net/misc/math.SE_community_ad_arXiv_edit.xcf.gz), so I went and [updated it again](http://vyznev.net/misc/math.SE_community_ad_arXiv_edit2.xcf.gz).

Comment: Ps. [Here's the .xcf file](http://vyznev.net/misc/math.SE_community_ad_arXiv_edit2.xcf.gz), in case someone else wants to update it for 1M. :) The font used is [Aller](http://www.identifont.com/find?font=Aller).

Comment: 994,223 preprints as on Dec 8th so perhaps this file will be useful soon :)

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Good timing too, since the 2015 ads collection is just around the corner. Let's hope ArXiv will keep adding exactly 100,000 items every year.

Comment: @Behaviour: and now they have one million! See also the plot at https://twitter.com/openscience/status/549752384491388928

Answer (score 51):

[image: GeoGebra]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6781/93957

Comment: That's not what I call "Free mathematics software" ...

Comment: @SamB: What's not free about it?

Comment: @AssadEbrahim: Does it seem to fit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software#Definition to you?

Comment: @SamB: Interesting.  They've changed their license recently it appears.  Quoting from the Wikipedia link:  while the source code is licensed under the terms of the GNU General Public License, the translation files, installers, and web services are licensed under non-GPL-compatible terms. Commercial use is prohibited without the purchase of a separate license.  It has been noted by the maintainer of the software in Debian GNU/Linux that these terms, **a change from earlier releases**, *prevent the resulting combined work from being considered free software and may be nondistributable.*

Comment: @SamB: Thanks for the reference

Comment: @AssadEbrahim: Ah. After looking at the terms shown on the site, the idea of it being in Debian naturally didn't cross my mind...  I wonder how hard it'd be to get a free fork caught up on the translations?

Answer (score 46):

[image: SageMath]

Answer (score 42):

[image: MIT OPEN COURSEWARE]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10078/93957

Answer (score 42):

[image: StackEdit]

Comment: I miss "\label{aa}" and "\eqref{aa}" functions, and also possibility to use some user-defined macros, e.g. \newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}. But nice!

Comment: NOTE: you can customize MathJax with your own macros in Settings->Extensions->MathJax->Tex configuration. See http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros.

Comment: thanks, I didn't dig deep enough in the settings!

Comment: downvoter???!!!

Answer (score 35):

[image: GAP - Group, Algorithms and Programming]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/community-promotion-ads-2013/11736#11736 which I've just posted a couple of weeks ago...

Comment: Thanks for sharing me. :-)

Answer (score 34):

[image: ProofWiki - online compendium of mathematical proofs.]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6782/93957

Comment: I’m not terribly keen on the idea of recommending this site: I find the house style rather opaque, verging on obfuscatory.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott it seems to me like they copied their style from TVtropes.

Comment: They also have a bizarrely convoluted and invasive sign-up process requiring you provide a CV and personal details such as your real name and phone number to verify your identity.

Answer (score 31):

[image: Wolfram Alpha]

Comment: lol... I never thought of advertising Wolfram since it is too popular.

Comment: See also previous discussion @ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3327/

Comment: And it's still valid: free ads for a commercial product, while there are good free CAS. I downvote.

Comment: @arbautjc I think wolframalpha isn't mainly a CAS, but something special, because of you don't need to know a bit of syntax to use it while for most CAS you need to know the correct syntax. Furthermore the basic functions of wolframalpha are free

Answer (score 29):

[image: writeLaTeX]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8288/93957

Comment: Could the $3$ downvoters explain their act?

Comment: At least I can explain mine: free ads for commercial product. No way.

Comment: @arbautjc This is not a commercial product.

Comment: Really? Then it's probably by mistake they put a "Pricing" link.

Comment: @arbautjc The pricing link is for upgrading one's account, the main features of writeLaTex are free.

Comment: Yes, like WolframAlpha and many others, the free stuff is here to push people to buy the commercial stuff. As I said, I won't upvote free ads to a commercial product.

Comment: @arbautjc Your reason isn't viable. Community promotion ads are for: $$\begin{align}
\circ &    \text{the site's twitter account }\\
 \circ &   \text{useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined}\\
\circ &    \text{interesting articles or findings for the curious}\\
 \circ &   \text{cool events or conferences}\\
\circ &    \text{anything else your community would genuinely be interested in}\\
\end{align}$$

Wolfram and writeLaTeX are perfectly compatible with that chart because of the second and last reasons.

Comment: It's not prescribed by MSE that ads are only for free sites. But it's my choice that I will downvote any ads for commercial ones. You asked for the reasons of downvoters, I gave you mine.

Comment: @arbautjc *"the free stuff is here to push people to buy the commercial stuff."* - not necessarily.

Comment: This discussion would never end. I perfectly accept, and understand, that we disagree. I'm not in the least trying to convince you. And on the other hand, there is no issue for you, since there are already more than enough upvotes for this one.

Comment: @arbautjc Je suis d'accord avec votre dernier commentaire :-) (Big thanks to G-translator)

Comment: I've used this one a lot.

Answer (score 29):

[image: Current Mathematics bounties]

Comment: +1, but, please--nicer theme! It would be great to have a different theme.  Someone with free time (like anyone has that) should write a similar script but with a theme more conducive to the MSE theme.

Comment: Yeah: "There are currently less than $e^\pi$ active bounties, worth $\pi^{e^2}$"

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a valid ad anyway, since it fails the "[image must] be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)" requirement (not to mention the size requirement).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The image works perfectly on Apple.SE even if it size is greater than 220x250 (it get displayed at the correct size through) and if it isn't hosted by imgur.

Comment: b.t.w: The add shows great results for its first appearance: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11920

Comment: Somewhat-significant bug: if you're not logged in, this redirects to the plain front page.

Comment: You may want to consider allowing https for this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12772/61349

Comment: How does this ad update? Does someone need to change it manually? Is there a system periodically checking the bounties and updating the image? It seems to be out of date at the moment; there are 57 bounties out right now.

Comment: but can this be updatable, like this really shows exactly how many bounties are there and the total reputation awarded for answering them all?

Answer (score 28):

[image: Khan|Academy]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8906/93957

Comment: Could the downvoter explain his act?

Comment: I upvoted this, but IMO, the biggest weakness of this ad has always been that it says nothing about what Khan Academy _is_. If you don't already know what it's about, there's nothing in this ad to tell you why you should click it (or upvote it, for that matter).

Comment: Yes, this ad is completely uninformative ...

Comment: It doesn't have to--it's **Khan Academy**, probably the *most popular* site listed here. (Plus, it's more informative than that **WolframAlpha** ad...)

Answer (score 24):

[image: A beautiful, free online graphing calculator]

Comment: Made in Mathematica for a lack of proper tools (not proudly). Please feel free to improve the post and especially the graphic (or down/up vote). The tool itself is very useful (at least to me). I added their standard tag to the found [original image source](https://www.facebook.com/desmosinc) and ensured dimension conformance.

Comment: Really valuable for its ability to create interactive Cartesian demos that can be shared over the Internet.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Crypto Stackexchange]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10558

Comment: Just FYI: the encrypted bit says 'crypto.stackexchange.com' (x3).

Answer (score 17):

[image: EXericeWIKI]

Comment: I wanted to start such a site myself. I am so happy it already exists. I hope it will grow further.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I'd be very glad if you could work/contribute to the site as well!

Comment: I think the exercises should be divided accordingly to the subject to which they belong to. Just in Probability, there are only 9 exercises but from completely different subjects, I think.
Maybe it could be ordered by subjects, like in a college degree. 
In probability section, you could have those considered to belong to introductory courses, then those of intermediate and advance level. It would really help if each section was structured as the branches of probabilities are in university degree all around the world. Good Luck! ;) If you need some help I may try, though I know very little.

Comment: I'd like to give the following link: a full set of solution to Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra (2nd edition) published online on wordpress. I'm not going to copy out all the solutions, but throwing a link up there would be a nice step.

https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/aadf/

Answer (score 14):

[image: AMS Graduate Student Blog - Read and write about topics that matter to you.]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9002/1761

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mathematica.SE]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11341/93957

Comment: I still dislike "funnest", but perhaps it only bothers me.

Comment: @Austin Mohr I agree, might be best to replace funnest with best. Not very imaginative but better.

Answer (score 12):

[image: LaTeX Search]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Puzzling]

Comment: Considering how you lot already have `puzzle` and `recreational-mathmatics` tags, I imagine the Puzzling SE would fit in quite well here.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Scientific Literature Digital Library & Search Engine]

Comment: Copy of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3385

Answer (score 10):

[image: SciRate]

Comment: Source: https://gist.github.com/stared/017c8af055f79aa7480f

Answer (score 8):

[image: Lollipop: A New Advanced TeX Format]

Comment: thank Dr. Khalighi

Comment: Really pretty logo.

Answer (score 5):

[image: ACADEMIA.SE]

Comment: I like the idea of promoting Academia.SE. But 3 differently styled texts (white on black, **pink** on white, black on white) looks... somewhat unprofessional, maybe. Oh, and 19 words (3 words «academia» included) seems to be too long for an ad.

Comment: Okay, I will try to ameliorate it! @GrigoryM

Comment: I'd prefer version without that black frame (with its text) and without pink font, maybe?

Comment: As I commented last year, I still think "Rocking your world" is in poor taste.

Answer (score 4):

[image: FactorDB: an integer factorization database]

Comment: Rather minimalistic, if anyone has an idea to improve...

Answer (score 2):

[image: ShareLaTeX]

Comment: Free ads for commercial product. I downvote.

Comment: @arbautjc Again, we disagree.

Comment: I know :-) There is also WolframAlpha below.

Answer (score 1):

[image: arXiv Analytics: specialized web portal dedicated to reading & discussing arXiv eprints]

Comment: It's either very late or a bit early to post new Community Ads proposals... The history suggests that we are just about to enter the new round (2015 ads).

Answer (score -4):

[image: DLMF|Nist]

Comment: I dislike this advert for two reasons. Firstly, it is implying that I, as a user of this site, use something I do not use. Secondly, it tells people that it is "okay not to know your functions!". This is (arguably) true when you get a certain level, but most students here will not be at that level yet... Also, being allowed to not know your functions is then extended (in the students minds) to "not knowing your derivatives" and so on until we get to "not knowing your definitions".

Comment: (I should say thought: I don't mind the site itself being advertised, just not with this advert.)

Comment: Upper half with text over formulas looks somewhat... messy, IMHO.

Comment: (And maybe this one also has just too many words...)

Comment: "Power up your memory with Digital Library of Mathematical Functions!" or brain implant jokes are better.

Comment: @user1729 I'm the author of this ad, over in [Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5278). I'm a research physicist and I can say with confidence that, while it is *not* OK not to know that e.g. [this formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E1) exists, it *is* OK not to memorize its exact details up to the very last constant. I think it is much more important to learn to know and use these resources - the DLMF, and previously A&S - than to memorize exactly the form of every relation you've ever used.

Comment: That said, I'm open to suggestions on how to improve this advert, both on the graphical and the content front. @FrenzYDT.'s  text, for example, could do; care to suggest a layout?

Answer (score -5):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is an example ad to demonstrate, with the site's twitter account. For the past two years it has not stayed above the 6 vote threshold, which is perfectly fine when the community has more relevant items to show each other.

Comment: what is bad with the Twitter account?

Comment: @dwarandae That's the wrong question. The correct question is: What is good about promoting it? There's much more interesting stuff to promote here.

Answer (score -6):

[image: DEREK|OWENS Math Courses]

Comment: Could the two downvoters explain their act?

Comment: I downvoted for two reasons. Firstly, I have no idea who Derek Owens is and what he does. Secondly, how do I know that you are not Derek Owens and are just trying to plug yourself? (The latter issue would be resolved by you just saying "Disclaimer: this ain't me".)

Comment: @user1729 1) If you saw what's in the background of the image you'll then know. 2) I'm not Derek Owens just as I'm not Sal Khan (I posted an add referencing Khan Academy).

Comment: Khan's academy is well-known and so advertising it would not be odd, but I (as a small sample population of members of this site) have never heard of Derek Owens. I have clicked on the link so I know that he runs some sort of youtube channel about maths. But then you haven't given me a reason to upvote it. So do lots of people. What stands out about it? (Also, as to your reply of "If you saw what's in the background of the image you'll then know", the advert tells me that he does maths. But then so do most of the adverts we are discussing here.)

Comment: @user1729 Because you didn't see the quality of his videos which are in my view way better than Khan's ones. The geometrical courses are also excellent especially for the esthetic part: better drawings than Khan's videos. See for example his series on trigonometry.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't see the quality of his videos because by this point I wasn't voting on the product, as it were, but the advert. It tells me that there is some guy called Derek Owens who does maths. Again, this is where Kahn Academy comes out on top. I have never watched a Kahn Academy video, but I know that if I did it would be teaching me something. It is an academy. Derek Owens might be doing magical maths card tricks for all I know... My point is that you need to change the advert to actually say something. "Derek Owens: Maths videos!"..."The Derek Owen's school of maths!"...

Comment: Okay I will try to improve the ad @user1729

Answer (score -6):

[image]

Comment: If anyone has a better picture for the ad of archive.org please edit my post.

Comment: I don't really see the reason to promote the Internet Archive on math.SE; the vast majority of the other advertisements are very focused towards math or related topics. (Also, is this just a screenshot of the current state of the website?)