# MathJax WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editor

I originally enquired about this at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162664 but misconstrued [Bakoma-TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28389) as a Mathjax editor. Please advise if anyone objects to this question.

<s>Barring [Bakoma-TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28389)</s>, are there any other WYSIWYG editors for MathJax?

To wit, I'm asking for a vaster WYSIWYG editor than that at Math StackExchange, with respect to [Feature request - but it woudn't be a feature, it'd be a blessing - editing panel and preview side-by-side - fighting lag on large answers!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10505/53259).  The tribulation on MathSE is that the preview panel is hidden below the input box. For desire of augmented productivity, I'm questing after a WYSIWYG editor in which I can view the preview/output on one monitor while working with the input on another monitor.

I tried those at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28389, but they don't seem to pertain to MathJax? For instance, if I input text without $, then writelatex.com fails to effect the output:

[image]

Comment: [StackEdit](http://stackedit.io/) seems to handle MathJax, at least according to their website: *You can render LaTeX mathematical expressions using MathJax, as on http://math.stackexchange.com.* However, I have never used this editor, I am not sure whether what are the differences between MarkDown used in that editor and on this site. StackEdit was also mentioned in one of the answers to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/mathjax-better-way-to-prepare-a-math-stackexchange-question).

Comment: There are many, many editors that support MathJax. A partial list is given [on MathJax's webpage](http://www.mathjax.org/community/mathjax-in-use/mathjax-in-use-applications/). Personally I have used [Qute](https://github.com/fbreuer/qute-html5) and am pretty happy with it (once you complete a paragraph it replaces it by the live preview, so it is about as close to WYSIWYG as one can have). If you are happy with LaTeX previewers, [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) and [Gummi](http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi) are both pretty good.

Comment: As to your final paragraph: WriteLaTeX expects a full LaTeX document. (As does Gummi mentioned in my previous post.) I think LyX sets up a dummy document in the background so you don't need to worry about that, but I am not sure.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you. It has since helped superlatively! Please feel free to answer.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thank you. I'll try them.

Comment: Perhaps the userscript [Side By Side Editing](http://stackapps.com/q/6461/36263) (which I've recently been adding some new features to) can help.

Answer (score 7):

Per [OP's request](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12967/mathjax-wysiwyg-editor?noredirect=1#comment51020_12967) I am reposting my comment as answer.

[StackEdit](http://stackedit.io/) seems to handle MathJax, at least according to their website:

> You can render LaTeX mathematical expressions using MathJax, as on  math.stackexchange.com.

However, I have never used this editor personally, so I am not sure whether what are the differences between [MarkDown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) used in that editor and on this site.

I have learned about existence of StackEdit from one of the answers to [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/mathjax-better-way-to-prepare-a-math-stackexchange-question) and also from an [community promotion ad](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/community-promotion-ads-2014/12165#12165) here at math.SE.

Comment: StackEdit seems to be in the midst of rolling out "version 5", which appears to replace MathJax integration with a "lightweight TeX implementation" called [KaTeX](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/).  However it appears to be missing some features, such as support for `\hline` in the `array` environment.

Comment: WYSIWYG does *not* mean "enter the markup language and see the results".  It means "edit the results and then get the markup language".

This failure mode is pervasive across the meta questions about stackexchange and makes it very difficult to locate the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

SaturnAPI offers side-by-side editing panel and preview like what you suggest. See this example: https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/equations-and-matrices

I am one of the devs for SaturnAPI, so feel free to ask me more about it.