# Adverts on Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, privileges, advertising

I was looking at the privileges on Mathoverflow, Stackexchange and Meta stack exchange and noticed that on these sites, there is a 200-rep privilege "reduce ads". Indeed, on these sites, every question I look at has adverts.

I was wondering why this isn't the case on Math.SE - there is no "reduce ads" privilege, and as far as I can tell no ads.

Comment: Just in case you're not aware of it, [AdBlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdBlock) works pretty well on SE sites.

Answer (score 14):

At present, only three SE sites carry commercial ads: Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User. They are banners placed below question title, in the sidebar, and between answers.

Example:

[image]

Consequently, these sites have the 200-rep privilege at which most of these banners are no longer shown.

There are no commercial ads on other sites yet. Although SE plans to expand ad sales to  other sites, listed below:

```
Android Enthusiasts   Arqade (video gamer)   Ask Different (Apple)  Ask Ubuntu   Database Administrators   Drupal  Game Development   Programmers   Security   SharePoint  Unix/Linux   Web Applications   WordPress
```

That the list of privileges on Meta Stack Exchange and on MathOverflow include the 200-rep reduced advertising privilege is simply a bug. In case of Meta this seems to be a [bug-by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89988/259867). Who knows how it came about on MathOverflow. If someone  complains on their meta, the bug might be fixed. Or not.

---

I emphasize that the above is about commercial ads. There are other banners present around SE networks, some of which are intra-network site promotions (example below), and others are [Community Ads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11920/147263). These are not disabled regardless of reputation.

[image: promotion]

Comment: How do you know about everything on SE?

Comment: Thanks! Is there a particular reason why ads are only being rolled out on certain sites? Is the long term aim to roll them out everywhere?

Comment: FWIW the ads are so subtle on SO that I never even thought of them as ads until I saw this post. At first I was scratching my head wondering "what ads?" until I saw the screencap.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: but be sure they work all the same ;)