# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/25812).

Comment: Here's the community ad post from last year: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/community-promotion-ads-2016

Comment: [Desmos](http://www.desmos.com/calculator), [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/), and [ISC](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced) are conspicuously missing.

Comment: As are [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), [Wolfram Functions](http://functions.wolfram.com), and [Wolfram Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com).

Comment: Someone should add the [derivative calculator](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/) to this list in the next community ads post, it shows free step-by-step solutions for any derivative; and also has a sister site for calculating [integrals](https://www.integral-calculator.com/).

Answer (score 79):

[image: YouTube channel of 3blue1brown]

Comment: Glad to see this here!  3blue1brown is the 3blue1bomb!

Comment: I had no idea that this was being advertised, awesome!

Comment: This made me understand linear algebra after using it (with headache) for 8 years!

Comment: I really enjoy watching your videos! Thank you for the effort you put it!

Answer (score 68):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [repost from last year](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22423/154545)

Answer (score 60):

[image: arXiv.org: the leading open access eprint repository]

Comment: [repost from last year](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22427/154545)

Answer (score 60):

[image: The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences]

Comment: [repost from last year](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22442/154545)

Answer (score 52):

[image: Approach0.xyz]

Answer (score 47):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: [repost from last year](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22425/154545)

Comment: Amazing math app as well as drawing / design tool

Answer (score 42):

[image: Sage Mathematical Software Environment]

Comment: Reposting [last year's version](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/24771/22912).

Answer (score 35):

[image: Desmos]

Comment: Love it for those who don't use super advanced graphing tools but still want to be able to draw integrals, parametric/polar equations, and more!

Answer (score 26):

[image: History of Science and Mathematics at Stack Exchange]

Comment: Source: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22447

Answer (score 23):

[image: Wolfram Alpha]

Comment: The evergreen math helper!

Comment: @JaideepKhare: That slogan seems more appropriate for the *Desmos* commercial. :-)

Answer (score 21):

[image: Overleaf: Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with real-time PDF preview]

Comment: Repost [last year's version](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22436/29335) since I was surprised it wasn't already suggested.  As a commenter mentioned on that post, Overleaf offers both free and paid services, in case that is a factor for anyone's decision. I enjoy the free service quite a lot...

Answer (score 20):

[image: www.cut-the-knot.org]

Comment: This image is 96×92 at the moment. Do you think you can get an official version at higher resolution? If not, it might make sense to create your own vector version of this (SVG or similar) and then export a suitably sized version from that. You also need to add a border, as far as I understand it.

Comment: Logo fixed. Thanks to Alexander Bogomolny - CTK webmaster.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Inverse Symbolic Calculator]

Answer (score 16):

[image: ProofWiki, the online compendium of mathematical proofs]

Comment: this needs more votes !

Answer (score 14):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 12):

[image: GAP - Group, Algorithms and Programming]

Comment: Copied from http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/community-promotion-ads-2016/22431#22431

Comment: link is not working for me? (took too long to respond)

Comment: @MCMastery thanks for reporting - I've checked, works fine for me. Could you try again, please?

Comment: now it works, guess server was just overloaded?

Comment: @MCMastery could be some random network glitch - usually works fine. Was useful to look at the ad, prompted by this - I've also updated the URL, changing http to https.

Answer (score 10):

[image: The Combinatorial Statistic Finder]

Answer (score 9):

[image: NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions]

Comment: Reposted from [yesteryear](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22419). Indispensable for evaluating many definite integrals.

Comment: That's pretty funny, given the reception the DLMF ad got the [first time around](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11954/30935) =P.

Answer (score 7):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes much sense to put a link in the description.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Wolfram Math World]

Answer (score 4):

[image: An open source graphing software]

Answer (score 1):

[image: mathsteps]

Comment: I am writing here, on behalf of mathsteps' [evykassirer](https://github.com/evykassirer) to welcome developers to join mathsteps development on Github. Also, if those who votes down mathsteps can provide an suggestion to mathsteps' community, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[image: MIT OCW]

Comment: Did you maybe notice the $300 \times 250$ dimensions requirement for ads?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician No. Thanks for pointing out. How can I resize it?

Comment: any good image editor should be able to do resizing or cropping as needed

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician I resized it... but the thing lost its beauty..;-(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Wolfram Functions]

Answer (score -1):

[image: GXWeb]

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Answer (score -3):

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that this picture can be used for community ads. The OP explicitly says: "The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI." (I suppose the 2018 is about to start anyway, so you might prepare image with correct dimensions for the new thread.)

Comment: Note that the new thread has been posted [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018)