# Clicking ad Approach-0 downloads a file named "download"

Tags: bug

Clicking ad downloads a file named "download". I think it has to do with the particular ad, [Approach-o](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25818/45937). Downloaded file looks like an HTML file, probably the site's home source. I also tried visiting approach0.xyz, same happens. Shouldn't this ad be removed till the site fixes the bug?

I'm on Chrome latest, on Windows 10.

Tagging it bug since I couldn't find a better tag.

Comment: Try it again, it seems that when you visit http:\\approach0.xyz it downloads but when you visit https:\\approach0.xyz it works like supposed to. I've edited the ad so it should redirect nicely (if editing the post is enough to edit ad).

Comment: @kingW3, don't know how to  make the particular ad come back - will try when it comes. Will be great if someone else can confirm if it's fixed, if they see the ad!

Answer (score 3):

The owner or developer of approach0 fixed the [issue](https://github.com/approach0/search-engine/issues/20), also as an precaution the ad was edited to https link.