# Let's downvote our sandbox to prevent edits from bumping it

Tags: feature-request, meta, bumping, sandbox

[Our sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/21813) (with a permanent vote score of **124**) is perpetually hogging attention near or at the top of our Meta homepage.

In contrast, [Physics StackExchange's sandbox](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/this-is-a-sandbox)'s activities rightly occur under the hood, because editing that sandbox does not bump it, thanks to its **-17** vote score, due to this prominent notice at its top:

> NB: It's hard not to like this meta post but please keep it downvoted to -8 or less (rather than upvoting it) so that it doesn't get bumped to the front meta page every time someone is experimenting in the sandbox, which usually is not interesting to anyone else.

**Let's emulate PSE's sensible setup: close our current sandbox, then create a new one with a similar directive that it be kept heavily downvoted.**

As usual: upvote for aye, downvote for nay.

---

**EDIT** to highlight pertinent comments:

1. GerryMyerson:

   > isn't it a good thing for the sandbox to be visible/prominent for those who might not otherwise know about it, or might forget about it?
2. MartinSleziak’s suggested workaround (may be more aggressive than desired):

   Profile$\to$Settings$\to$Tag watching & ignoring$\to$Sandbox

Comment: Iirc I needed to get the SE team involved when I created the original sandbox, e.g. [see here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts#comment22087_4666), but I don't recall if it involved any more than that (twas over a decade ago).

Comment: Can't currently downvote it - it's locked. That said, my eyes just pass over it automatically these days, but wouldn't mind doing what you suggest, if I could.

Comment: Well, feel free to figure out what needs to be done, and come back here when you want those downvotes. Like I said, not an issue for me, but happy to makes things better for other.

Comment: Definitely in support of this idea. That the sandbox is bumped all the time is quite annoying.

Comment: Maybe the SE team has an easy way to change the votes on the current sandbox. That would be the easiest fix.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks. [I've asked](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018#comment163856_27800) the SE team member, whose comment you linked above, to take a look.

Comment: Of all the things that bother me about stackexchange sites, I think the repeated bumping of the sandbox bothers me the least. Anyway, isn't it a good thing for the sandbox to be visible/prominent for those who might not otherwise know about it, or might forget about it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good point! This changes my position from pro-DownvoteTheSandbox to being on the fence.

Comment: Personally, I do not mind seeing the sandbox on the frontpage. (In the other words, I haven't added ([meta-tag:sandbox]) to my ignored tags. A tangential question - naturally following from this post - what is the tag (sandbox) intended for? Should it only be used on sandboxes, or for questions *about* sandboxes, too?

Comment: Re: my recent EDIT: @MartinSleziak "[*Sorry for being aggressive - if that's what you meant to say*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61562926#61562926)". Not at all, haha; to be super clear: I was echoing your implicit point that ignoring the 'Sandbox' tag has the side-effect of aggressively filtering out not just the Mathematics Sandbox but also discussion threads like this page.

Comment: The Physics Sandbox is now -18.

Comment: It has score -19 now.

Comment: Downvoting will not represent users’ ideas of the sandbox accurately.